# What is required to make this treemap plot work?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Been trying to get treemap to work but the output is blank and not sure why.
If I take an example from the web and place it into my code the the output works fine - but when I try to use my data it does not output.

The sample code is..

```
library(plotly)

labels = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "B1", "B2")
parents = c("", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "", "B1")
values = c("11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "20", "30")

fig <- plot_ly(
  type="treemap",
  labels=labels,
  parents=parents,
  values=values,
  marker=list(colorscale='Reds'))

fig
```

The data source I am using is data frame and when I apply the data sources to the above example it simply does not work. So, I can only assume it is my data frame and I don't know why as I have tried all I know.

My data Code..

```
Continents_tmap <- df1 %>%
    group_by(Continent,Country.x) %>%
    summarise(Deaths = sum(Deaths))## %>%

Continents_tmap <- data.frame(Continents_tmap)

labels <- Continents_tmap$Country.x
parents <- Continents_tmap$Continent
values <- Continents_tmap$Deaths
```

My ui code  ..

```
tabPanel( "TreeMap",  plotlyOutput("tmap1")
                        )
```

My server side code....

```
output$tmap1 <- renderPlotly({
        plot_ly(
        type="treemap",
        labels=labels,
        parents=parents,
        values=values,
        marker=list(colorscale='Reds'))
    })
```

Regards

I got it to work using highchart but still not in plotly - my code for highchart is

```
 output$tmap1 <- renderHighchart({
        Continents_tmap %>%
            filter(Continent == input$continent_2) %>%
            group_by(Country.x) %>%
            summarise(pts = sum(Deaths), fgpct = sum(Deaths)) %>%
            hchart("treemap",
                   hcaes(
                       name = Country.x,
                       value = pts,
                       color = fgpct
                   )) %>%
            hc_title(text = "Continent- Country Deaths") %>%
            hc_subtitle(text = "Deaths Rating")
        
    })
```

Comment: Please share your data using the output of `dput(Continents_tmap)`.